# Algorithm for Print elements of array above it's diagonal

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I need to print the elements of an array that are above its diagonal.
For example:

Let's take a 3x3 matrix.

1, 2, 3,

4, 5, 6,

7, 8, 9

Now I need to print the elements 2 - 6 - 3 (in this pattern)

So far I'm able to come up with the below code that does return values in correct order but only of the diagonal above the middle diagonal. I'm not able to move it up.

```
for (int j = 0 ; j <=n; j++)
{
    System.out.print(arr[j] [j+1] + " ");
}
```

---

#### Solved

I actually needed to traverse the array in a diagonal way. Following is the code:

```
int n = arr.length;     
int m = 0;
int j = 0;

for (int k = 0; k<n; k++){
    for (int i = k; i < n ; i++)
    {
        m = i+1;
        if (j < n & m < n)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[j][m] + " ");
            j++;
            m++;
        }
    } j=0;
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: I really don't understand this question

Comment: Look, I need to print the elements of an array that are above its middle diagonal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i,j,k;

i=0;
while (i<n) // nXm matrix
{
    k=0;
    j=i+1;
    while (j<m && k<n)
    {
        System.out.print(arr[k][j] + " ");
        j++;
        k++;
    }

    i++;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it better to use `for` loop for a definite loop instead of `while`?

Comment: @mok It doesn't matter, does it?

Comment: Yes obviously. But I think in small codes like these it doesn't matter.

Comment: This one would come in handy for a better time complexity algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { //n = arr.length
    for (int j=i+1; j < n; j++) 
        System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the correct values but I need them in a diagonal order.

Comment: @YehCheez- Ok, try this. It has the format you want.

Comment: @YehCheez- Indeed it's your right. but I asked cause my answer is right! :) .And you're welcome.

Comment: This doesn't print in the required order.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay : Obviously prints. You can try it or ask the OP.

Comment: @mok It prints `2 3 6 ` instead of `2 6 3`.

Comment: @RikayanBandyopadhyay- So it's correct! cause OP needs the loops to print the items row by row although he's said differently in the question. He said 2 3 6 is correct in the comments, that's why he says `Awesome! Thanks` after I changed the code to this.

Comment: @YehCheez, if what mok says is true, edit the question accordingly.

Comment: @mok I totally wrote the question wrong. I was supposed to write traverse instead of print. So I'll change the code accordingly. However, your code was correct in that way. And I've also wrote the code too.